# Is this valid? I'm getting a missing ) error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I keep getting `Uncaught SyntaxError: missing )` after argument list in the console and the html is not inserting before the element of the class. What am I missing?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $( "<div><h3 class="second_and_third_member">2nd Member</h3></div>" ).insertBefore( ".second-member" );
    $( "<div><h3 class="second_and_third_member">3rd Member</h3></div>" ).insertBefore( ".third-member" );
});
```

Comment: Just check the syntax highlighting. Does it make sense in your script?

Comment: You have an error with the string there. You need to use `+` to sum up strings or use `'` if you need to use `"` in string\

Comment: Someone here was suggesting `Specsavers` to me. :D

Answer (score 2):

It's because you are using the wrong inner quotes (" instead of ').

```
$(document).ready(function() 
    {
        $("<div><h3 class='second_and_third_member'>2nd Member</h3></div>").insertBefore('.second-member');
        $("<div><h3 class='second_and_third_member'>3rd Member</h3></div>").insertBefore('.third-member');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Change double inverted comma to single. Because they are breaking the string.

```
$( '<div><h3 class="second_and_third_member">2nd Member</h3></div>' ).insertBefore( ".second-member" );
$( '<div><h3 class="second_and_third_member">3rd Member</h3></div>' ).insertBefore( ".third-member" );
```

Comment: Thanks! I see it, I understand.